# Needing to generate an expiration time

Tags: php, html

Currently I have the following format required when filling out the initial form which asked for the time remaining until the end of shift (EOS)

```
Hour's till EOS: <input type="text" name="tdr_eos" value="HH:MM:SS">
```

This moves them on to the next page which will take the time they provided and turn that into seconds to loop them back to page one using the following php code.

```
$timeArr = array_reverse(split(":", $eos));
$seconds = 0;
foreach($timeArr as $key => $value)
{
if($key>2) break;
$seconds =  $seconds  + pow(60, $key) * $value;
```

what I need to do is create a visual display for what time the refresh will take place. I tried creating the following variable -- after collecting the get value from the previous form of course.

```
$exp_time = $eos + date("H:i");
```

However all that will do is add the hours to the current time.  It doesn't actually add in the minutes or seconds. How can I get it to display the exact time that the page will expire?

Comment: Why aren't you using PHPs built in date/time functions?  like: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_create_from_format.asp

Comment: `date` uses the current date/time, unless you pass a timestamp as second parameter

Comment: I am using php's date/time functions but I need to add the values given in the previous form to it I have it working on adding it to the hours but not the minutes or seconds.

Answer (score 0):

What about
`$exp_time = date("H:i", ($eos + time()));` ?

`time()` gives you the current time stamp. `date()` formats a time stamp.